# Did the Star Trek TNG font originate in Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, the-temple-of-doom

I was watching *Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom* (1984), and the font in the [opening credits](https://annyas.com/screenshots/updates/indiana-jones-and-the-temple-of-doom-1984-steven-spielberg/) looked remarkably familiar:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Is that the font of *Star Trek: The Next Generation* (1987)?**  Or at least designed by the same artist?

[image: Star Trek: The Next Generation opening titles screenshot, "Starring PATRICK STEWART as Captain Jean-Luc Picard"]

For what it is worth, both were released by Paramount.

Related question for TOS: [Was the font used in the Star Trek wordmark created for the show, or was it a re-purposed font?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102363/102339)

Comment: https://freefontsfamily.com/crillee-font-free-download/ - It would appear that the font significantly pre-dates both the TNG show and the Indiana Jones movie

Comment: Crillee Italic is the font used for the _TNG_ credits, but it doesn't appear to be the same font used in the _Temple of Doom_ credits. Take note of the capital letter 'E,' which has a curved spine in the _Temple of Doom_ credits, and a straight spine in the Crillee Italic font.

Comment: They're not the same at all.  Other than both being italic the shapes are different, the proportions are different, the spacing is different.  I honestly don't see how you can think they're the same.  There isn't a single glyph in common except "I" and there's really only 1 way to draw that in a sans serif font.

Comment: Yes, these have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @LogicDictates And the shape of the capital "K" is also totally different.

Comment: Downvoting because once the screenshots are placed next to each other, it's easy to spot that these aren't the same font. If there's a different font used in TNG somewhere which is more similar, the question should show a picture of it. Otherwise, "does not show any research effort" seems a fair description.

Comment: The K and R are both different, in the same way.

Comment: And how about the W?   And the Star Trek font even has some minor serifs.

Comment: They are completely unrelated. And since there is not "obvious question" close reason, let's answer this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is little to no similarity in the actual glyphs. I suspect you're getting confused by both being a sans serif font having a similar capitalization, font weight, italicization and using a bright block color. That may seem like a lot of similarities but none of these (other than the sans serif) are related to the actual font.

I've lined up all the same capital letters that the examples share, hoping this helps you see that there are massive differences in the actual glyphs themselves. The only ones that look remotely similar are CPT; the others look completely different in terms of curvature and proportionality.

[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]

Comment: W..... ........

Comment: @ThePopMachine Whoops, fixed

Answer (score 11):

**No, the two are completely and obviously different.**

The A E W R K are completely different (rounded in the Indiana Jones, squarer in TNG). Other looks at credits show major differences in the M and B. That's just from a quick look.

Comment: They don't look "unrelated", they look very similar in places

Comment: @Valorum What places?  Other than the fact that they are both sans serif representations of characters of the Latin alphabet, and the "I" glyphs have the same shape (as I noted above) I don't see any similarity with respect to the standard ways that glyphs are measured.  Eyeballing it, I don't even believe the italic angle is the same.

Comment: @DavidW -They look similar enough to me that they might be in the same font 'family'. We have a pretty solid identification of the trek font as Crillee. What is the font used in the Indiana Jones film?

Comment: As OP notes, AEWRK all have completely different shapes; the A, E and W don't even have the same number of _strokes_.  They can't be in the same family, that's not how a font family works.

Comment: The Star Trek font actually isn't even completely sans serif!

Comment: @ThePopMachine So the ST font is *comically sans serif*?  (Rim-shot).  I'll be here all week, and remember to tip your servers on your way out.